# Framing corners

Tags: framing, carpentry

Is there a prefered method to framing an interior wall corner?
I am re-finishing my basement and in the process of framing my small bathroom, hallway, small bedroom and living area.
Just trying to make sure I do this right.
My opinion is that #2 seems to be the best option.

[image]

Comment: There are many ways to frame corners, it can or should have a lot to do with materials. If you have a lot of short block, you can block across studs where a wall intersects, or run the blocks vertically like a stud, but in pieces and allow half the blocks to catch the drywall. I don't have time to elaborate, otherwise I would post this as a small part of an answer... In essence, any solid wood to wood connection that drywall can attach to that is an 1" or more in a corner will work. If you are insulating, then there are small differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If maximizing insulation in the corner is your number 1 concern, then option 1 (though I'd do it with a strip of 5/8 plywood, rather than clips) is good.

Option 2 (frequently called a california corner) is better in terms of giving easy bearing to drywall.

Option 3 is poor for insulation and doesn't optimize wood use. It's useful in situations where you need a post.

Comment: Thank you for your opinions. Based on your opinions I will go with option two because all the walls will be interior walls and I will not have to insulate them.